# fedex integration not working in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an developer account with fedex and follow these steps http://www.cobbconsulting.net/magento-fedex-setup.html
and
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/

after complete all setup at checkout page it's show no shipping quotes are available

there are no errors why?

any help?

Comment: In admin, there is a setting in Fedex, "Debug", enable it and see the corresponding log files. More than likely, either there is some config wrong, or you might not be having the weights assigned to products.

Comment: @ Shakir Khan : Is it solve your problem, could you pls help me http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56921/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-rathinam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you fill all required credentials in magento admin and after sign up testing account you can find all credentials like account no,account meter,key etc but password they mail you in your email

Comment: @ anjali nagar : Hi sister, i am completely struggle with Fedex - magento   configuration, how can i solve, all my details post this chat room, let me escape form this error, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56921/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-rathinam